# php and aerospike - error in setting data

Tags: php, aerospike

I am using aerospike on ubuntu.

I am able to set and get records on/from aerospike on the command line.

In PHP, I am able to instantiate the AeroSpike class, but when i try to add some data to it, it says "AEROSPIKE_ERR_NAMESPACE_NOT_FOUND".

Surprisingly, the error code is 20, where as it should be 501 as per the docs. There is no such error code 20 defined in the api.

https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-nodejs/blob/master/docs/status.md

Code, that I tried.

```
<?php
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
ini_set( 'error_reporting', E_ALL );

// set the records to never expire unless specified otherwise
define( 'RECORD_TIME_TO_LIVE', 0 );

$config = array(
    "hosts" => array(
        array( "addr" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 3000 )
    )
);

$db = new Aerospike( $config );

// failure check
if ( !$db->isConnected() ) {
    echo "Failed to connect to the Aerospike server [{$db->errorno()}]: {$db->error()}\n";
    exit( 1 );
}

$key = $db->initKey("infosphere", "characters", 1);

$put_vals = array("name" => "Scruffy", "Occupation" => "The Janitor");

$status = $db->put($key, $put_vals, RECORD_TIME_TO_LIVE);

if($status == Aerospike::OK) {
    echo "Record written.\n";
} elseif ($status == Aerospike::ERR_RECORD_EXISTS) {
    echo "The Aerospike server already has a record with the given key.\n";
} else {
    echo "[{$db->errorno()}] :".$db->error();
}

$db->close();
?>
```

Any help is welcome.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the namespace "infosphere" defined in your Aerospike server config?

https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/namespace/

Default namespace present are only test and bar. Any other additional namespaces have to be defined and Aerospike server restarted to get the new namespace working.

I will check into the error codes.

Comment: Yes, figured that out after a lot of searching :) Thanks for confirming it though.